# Converting randomly selected elements to binary representation

Tags: r, binary

Suppose I got `string_a <- c('1', '3', '4', '9' ,'8')` and I randomly picked two elements from `string_a` using the `sample()` function. Assume that I got `3` and `8` as a result.

My question is, how can I obtain their indices(position) of `3` and `8` in `string_a` and represent them in this form: `01001`, where 1 represents the index of the randomly selected number and 0 represents unselected indices.

More examples:

if `1` and `3` are randomly selected, the binary representation would be `11000`

if `9` and `8` are randomly selected, the binary representation would be `00011`

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to get a logical vector and then coerce to binary with `as.integer`, paste it together

```
paste(as.integer(string_a %in% sample(string_a, 2)), collapse="")
#[1] "01010"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# assume x to be 
x = c('3','9')
paste0(as.numeric(match(string_a, x,nomatch = 0)>0), collapse = "")
```